# Wrapping a command (parametrically) - csname woes

Tags: patching, renewcommand, csname, expandafter

I would like to "wrap" an existing command with another command.

For example, suppose that there is one command

```latex
\cmda
```

I would like that each time this is called we end up executing:

```latex
\wrapper{some text}{\cmda}
```

If this was only one command, I know how to do this:

```latex
\let\oldcmda{\cmda}
\renewcommand{\cmda}{\wrapper{some text}{\oldcmda}}
```

However, what I would like is that this procedure is automated.

For example:

```latex
\wrapcmd{cmda}{Some text for cmda}
\wrapcmd{cmdb}{Some other text for cmdb}
\wrapcmd{cmdc}{No text for cmdc}
```

Looking at this SO for many hours, I managed to realized that the various "patch" commands either append something at the beginning or at the end, but wouldn't work for this case.

Here is my "almost working solution":

```latex
\def\oldcmd{}
\newcommand{\wrapcmd}[2]{%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\oldcmd\csname #1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\wrapper{#2}{\oldcmd}}%
}
```

This works for one command.
However, for the case of multiple commands, it doesn't work, because `\oldcmd` is reused.

I'm trying to cobble together a solution that instead of using `\oldcmd` would expand to `\old#1`, with another `\csname`. However I am stuck.

Here's a minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\cmda}{CommandA}
\newcommand{\cmdb}{CommandB}

\newcommand{\wrapper}[2]{about (#1): #2}

\def\oldcmd{}
\newcommand{\wrapcmd}[2]{%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\oldcmd\csname #1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\wrapper{#2}{\oldcmd}}%
}

\begin{document}

Before:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda
    \item \cmdb
\end{itemize}

\wrapcmd{cmda}{This is comment for cmda}
\wrapcmd{cmdb}{This is comment for cmdb}


After:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda
    \item \cmdb
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

As you can see, now `\cmda` has the original content of `cmdb`.

[image: result]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, every call of `\wrapcmd` uses always the same macro `\oldcmd` as backup, so you keep overwriting it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\cmda}{CommandA}
\newcommand{\cmdb}{CommandB}

\newcommand{\wrapper}[2]{about (#1): #2}

\newcommand{\wrapcmd}[2]{%
   \expandafter\let\csname old@\string#1\endcsname=#1%
   \renewcommand{#1}{\wrapper{#2}{\csname old@\string#1\endcsname}}%
}

\begin{document}

Before:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda
    \item \cmdb
\end{itemize}

\wrapcmd{\cmda}{This is comment for cmda}
\wrapcmd{\cmdb}{This is comment for cmdb}

After:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda
    \item \cmdb
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've implemented a slightly different (but safer) syntax, such that you should use `\wrapcmd{\cmda}{...}` instead of your `\wrapcmd{cmda}{...}`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 
Happy to leave behind all those expandafter!

Answer (score 4):

You want that `\cmda` becomes `\wrapper{some text}{\cmda}`, but of course you need an alias for `\cmda` or you'd get infinite recursion.

Your attempt is almost good, but `\let\oldcmda{\cmda}` is wrong: no braces should be used. And it's risky because `\cmda` might be a robust command. The safer way is to do

```
\NewCommandCopy\oldcmda\cmda
\renewcommand{\cmda}{\wrapper{some text}{\oldcmda}}
```

Now we want to abstract this. You might decide to use the names, instead of the macros, which is indeed easier:

```
\newcommand{\wrapcmd}[2]{%
  % alias the command
  \expandafter\NewCommandCopy\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \wrapper{#2}{\csname old#1\endcsname}%
  }%
}
```

Now a call such as

```
\wrapcmd{cmda}{Some text}
```

will do the same as the initial attempt. But this has the drawback that the new definition of `\cmda` will contain `\csname oldcmda\endcsname`, not `\oldcmda`.

Can we do better and get that `\cmda` will become `\wrapper{Some text}{\oldcmda}`? Yes, of course we can.

```
\newcommand{\wrapcmd}[2]{%
  % alias the command
  \expandafter\NewCommandCopy\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \unexpanded{\wrapper{#2}}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname old#1\endcsname}%
  }%
}
```

Let's try your example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\cmda}{CommandA}
\newcommand{\cmdb}{CommandB}

\newcommand{\wrapper}[2]{about (#1): #2}

\newcommand{\wrapcmd}[2]{%
  % alias the command
  \expandafter\NewCommandCopy\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \unexpanded{\wrapper{#2}}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname old#1\endcsname}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Before:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda
    \item \cmdb
\end{itemize}

\wrapcmd{cmda}{This is comment for cmda}
\wrapcmd{cmdb}{This is comment for cmdb}

After:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda \\ \texttt{\meaning\cmda}
    \item \cmdb \\ \texttt{\meaning\cmdb}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Of course you want to use something different from `old` as a prefix.

[image]

You can avoid all those `\expandafter` tokens, though, and use the command instead of the name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % wider textwidth

\newcommand{\cmda}{CommandA}
\newcommand{\cmdb}{CommandB}

\newcommand{\wrapper}[2]{about (#1): #2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\wrapcmd}{mm}
 {
  \andreacensi_wrapcmd:Ncn #1 {andreacensi@\cs_to_str:N #1} { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \andreacensi_wrapcmd:NNn
 {
  \NewCommandCopy #2 #1
  \renewcommand #1 { \wrapper{#3}{#2} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \andreacensi_wrapcmd:NNn { Nc }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Before:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda
    \item \cmdb
\end{itemize}

\wrapcmd{\cmda}{This is comment for cmda}
\wrapcmd{\cmdb}{This is comment for cmdb}

After:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda \\ \texttt{\meaning\cmda}
    \item \cmdb \\ \texttt{\meaning\cmdb}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The trick is to use a further argument, which will be the alias name for the old macro, to `\andreacensi_wrapcmd:NNn` (the `c` variant will build the command).

[image]

Comment: I tried this code - something very weird happens.

For context, the commands wrapped are used in math mode.

If I wrap them with this code, then \mathsf{...}, \mathrm{...}, \mathcal{...} produce empty strings. 

I have difficulty providing a minimal example because it's a very large project.

Does this ring a bell?

Comment: @AndreaCensi I suspected your real application was different. Sorry, but the information is really insufficient. Please open a new question with the details of what you're *really* after.

Comment: Coming back to this to say that the solution worked perfectly. The error I had been seeing was a mistake on my part in implementing the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Some facts:

- Non-delimited macro arguments consisting of a single token don't need to be nested in curly braces.
- `\csname..\endcsname` is used for creating a control-sequence-token.
- The `\expandafter\endcsname\csname`-trick can be used for creating several control sequence-tokens in a row:
  `\csname foo\expandafter\endcsname\csname bar\expandafter\endcsname\csname baz\endcsname`
  yields
  `\foo\bar\baz`
  by triggering a single expansion-step on the first `\csname`.

A common trick is to have a helper-macro do the actual work which gets as arguments all the control-sequence-tokens needed, while within the definition of the main macro/user-level-macro using the `\expandafter\endcsname\csname`-trick for creating and passing as arguments to the helper-macro all the control-sequence-tokens needed:

```latex
%Format: LaTeX2e
%
\newcommand\wrapcmd[2]{%
  % \wrapcmd{foo}{argument} yields: \wrapcmdhelper\foo\oldfoo{argument}
  \expandafter\wrapcmdhelper\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname old#1\endcsname{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\wrapcmdhelper[3]{%
  % Probably \protected\def instead of \def?
  \csname @ifdefinable\endcsname#2{\let#2=#1\def#1{\wrapper{#3}{#2}}}%
}%
%%===============================================================================
%% Testing:
%%===============================================================================
\wrapcmd{cmda}{Some text for cmda}
\message{^^J\string\cmda=\meaning\cmda^^J}
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\wrapcmd{cmdb}{Some other text for cmdb}
\message{^^J\string\cmdb=\meaning\cmdb^^J}
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\wrapcmd{cmdc}{No text for cmdc}
\message{^^J\string\cmdc=\meaning\cmdc^^J}
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\stop
```

Console Output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

\cmda=macro:->\wrapper {Some text for cmda}{\oldcmda }

\cmdb=macro:->\wrapper {Some other text for cmdb}{\oldcmdb }

\cmdc=macro:->\wrapper {No text for cmdc}{\oldcmdc }
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

---

Probably a routine `\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{NameOfCs}` → `⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs` where *⟨stuff not in braces⟩* may be empty also does the trick:

```latex
%Format: LaTeX2e
%
\makeatletter
%%===============================================================================
%% End \romannumeral-driven expansion safely:
%%===============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%===============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%===============================================================================
%% \wrapcmd{<csname>}{<arg>}
%%===============================================================================
\newcommand\wrapcmd[2]{%
  \CsNameToCsToken\@ifdefinable{old#1}{%
     \CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\let{old#1}={#1}%
     %\CsNameToCsToken\protected\expandafter\def\expandafter{#1}\expandafter{%
     \CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\def\expandafter{#1}\expandafter{%
       \romannumeral
       \CsNameToCsToken\UD@PassFirstToSecond{old#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral\wrapper{#2}}%
     }%
  }%  
}%
\makeatother
%%===============================================================================
%% Testing:
%%===============================================================================
\wrapcmd{cmda}{Some text for cmda}
\message{^^J\string\cmda=\meaning\cmda^^J}
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\wrapcmd{cmdb}{Some other text for cmdb}
\message{^^J\string\cmdb=\meaning\cmdb^^J}
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\wrapcmd{cmdc}{No text for cmdc}
\message{^^J\string\cmdc=\meaning\cmdc^^J}
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\stop
```

Console-output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

\cmda=macro:->\wrapper {Some text for cmda}{\oldcmda }

\cmdb=macro:->\wrapper {Some other text for cmdb}{\oldcmdb }

\cmdc=macro:->\wrapper {No text for cmdc}{\oldcmdc }
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

---

If the patched variants of commands are to be used only within code written by you so that patches to commands shall not affect code written by others/shall not affect macros when being used in package-code and the like provided by others, then you might consider not patching commands at all but just defining a macro `\wrapcmd{NameOfCs}{arg}` which does `\wrapper{arg}{\NameOfCs}` and within your code using that instead of `\NameOfCs`:

```latex
%Format: LaTeX2e
%
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\wrapcmd[2]{%
  \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{\wrapper{#2}}%
}%
% Dummy-definition for \wrapper
\newcommand\wrapper[2]{\message{^^J\detokenize{\wrapper{#1}{#2}}^^J}}%

\wrapcmd{cmda}{Some text for cmda}
\wrapcmd{cmdb}{Some other text for cmdb}
\wrapcmd{cmdc}{No text for cmdc}

\stop
```

Console-output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> 
\wrapper {Some text for cmda}{\cmda }

\wrapper {Some other text for cmdb}{\cmdb }

\wrapper {No text for cmdc}{\cmdc }
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

In order to ensure that the result is delivered by triggering two expansion-steps you can wrap this into `\romannumeral`-expansion:

```latex
%Format: LaTeX2e
%
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\wrapcmd[2]{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
  \expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}%
              {\UD@stopromannumeral\wrapper{#2}}%
}%
\makeatother

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \wrapcmd{cmda}{Some text for cmda}%
}%
\message{^^J\string\temp=\meaning\temp^^J}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \wrapcmd{cmdb}{Some other text for cmdb}%
}%
\message{^^J\string\temp=\meaning\temp^^J}


\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\temp
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \wrapcmd{cmdc}{No text for cmdc}%
}%
\message{^^J\string\temp=\meaning\temp^^J}

\stop
```

Console-output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

\temp=macro:->\wrapper {Some text for cmda}{\cmda }

\temp=macro:->\wrapper {Some other text for cmdb}{\cmdb }

\temp=macro:->\wrapper {No text for cmdc}{\cmdc }
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to expand the command immediately, you can define `\oldcmd` local to a group.  If you have to wait, then you will need a global macro with a different name for each usage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\cmda}{CommandA}
\newcommand{\cmdb}{CommandB}

\newcommand{\wrapper}[2]{about (#1): #2}

\newcommand{\wrapcmd}[2]{\bgroup
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\oldcmd\csname #1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #1\endcsname{\wrapper{#2}{\oldcmd}}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}

Before:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda
    \item \cmdb
\end{itemize}

\wrapcmd{cmda}{This is comment for cmda}
\wrapcmd{cmdb}{This is comment for cmdb}


After:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cmda
    \item \cmdb
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```